# Trailing space in search brings up every database entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, cpanel

I set up an SQL database for my site to search for specific keyword related pages, it works fine but when i put a space at the end or just search for a space in general it brings up all entries in my database. It doesnt do this for spaces between words, just a leading and trailing spaces. Is there a way to configure the database or the keywords in it so it wouldn't do that?

```
#   Name        Type           Collation               Null Default Extra
1   id          int(11)                                 No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
2   title       varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
3   description text            latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
4   keywords    text            latin1_swedish_ci       No  None    
5   link        varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None    
6   pic         varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
```

Comment: Can you please post your query. It sounds like you might be using the `%` operator, but it's hard to know without some context.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you are running.  Also, sample data is very useful.

Comment: Sorry im not sure where to find the query, not sure if that helps but i pasted the structure above.